# Resize images with ImageMagick to one of several aspects

Tags: batch, imagemagick, aspect-ratio

I have a collection of images that I process with ImageMagick in a bash script. It loops over the images in a folder. Most of them are in 3:2 format, but some are 4:3, 2:1 and 1:1. However, they are not all perfectly cropped to their aspect ratios, causing layout issues. If I have an image that is 3.01:2 I would like it to be forced into 3:2.

Currently I use the resize command below. Previously I have used scaling and cropping to force-fill 3:2, but that wrongly crops images with other aspect ratios.

```
convert -resize 300x200
```

I would like to force the images to the closest of a list of sizes, resizing and cropping to fit. I am fine with defining pixel sizes or (preferably) aspect ratios.

I cobbled together this in the bash script, which gets me something I can test against say a glorious array of if checks. Note that $filename comes from elsewhere:

```
aspect=$(ffmpeg -i "_originals/$filename"*.jpg 2>&1 | egrep -o "DAR ([0-9]+:[0-9]+)" | cut -f2 -d " " | sed 's/:/ /')
ratio=$(echo $aspect |awk '{printf "%.2f", $1/$2}')
printf "$ratio\n"
```

Comment: Use something to read the X/Y dimension, calc the ratio and match it to a selection?

Comment: Yes, that would roughly be what I am after. But I don't know how I would go about chaining it together. I would guess exiftool to read and then do some calculations?

Comment: You could also use [`identify`](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) which also has a [MAN page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/identify) so it might be available. The image dimension isn't really part of the exif information but rather a fundamental of the image structure in most formats I know.